# Countifs with array formula to collect data

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, countif

I have a raw data that contains types of defect (EC,VC,BC,NC).

first type of defect calculation (EC,VC,BC).
For example if i want to collect the EC defects, I will collect all the rows that contain EC=0 & if the EC is score down to 0 twice in the same row it will count as 1 EC only in this raw.
Same goes for VC & BC.

Second Type of defect calculation (NC)
Same calculation of the above but if the NC defect was repeated on the same row it will be summed.

I have the headers containing VC,EC,BC,NC above each column containing the score.

What i need here to calculate each raw containing defects.

I tried the below formula for VC,EC,BC.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(E2:E)=2,"EC",IF(LEN(E2:E)=0,IFERROR(1/0),IF(COUNTIFS($E$1:$BH$1,"EC",$E:$BH,0)>=1,1,0))))
```

The formula is working without the array formula, but will be hard to drag each time the data is updated.

Also, Tried the below for NC.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(H2:H)=2,"NC",IF(LEN(H2:H)=0,IFERROR(1/0),COUNTIFS($E$1:$BH$1,"NC",$E:$BH,0))))
```

Sample Sheet: [Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TtaHR4JhEUCjGu-eBbl0frS_WN5mRrubtV2SZDDLYAU/edit#gid=0)

Comment: @player0 I added the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"EC"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(FILTER(
 INDIRECT("E3:"&ADDRESS(MAX((E:Z<>"")*(ROW(A:A))), COLUMNS(1:1))), 
 E1:1="EC")=0, 1, )),,9^9))))>0, 1, 0))}
```

---

```
={"VC"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(FILTER(
 INDIRECT("E3:"&ADDRESS(MAX((E:Z<>"")*(ROW(A:A))), COLUMNS(1:1))), 
 E1:1="VC")=0, 1, )),,9^9))))>0, 1, 0))}
```

---

```
={"BC"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(FILTER(
 INDIRECT("E3:"&ADDRESS(MAX((E:Z<>"")*(ROW(A:A))), COLUMNS(1:1))), 
 E1:1="BC")=0, 1, )),,9^9))))>0, 1, 0))}
```

---

```
={"NC"; ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(FILTER(
 INDIRECT("E3:"&ADDRESS(MAX((E:Z<>"")*(ROW(A:A))), COLUMNS(1:1))), 
 E1:1="NC")=0, 1, 0), SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(E1:1, "NC"))^0))}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @player0 solved my issue.